# Message signing disabled (dangerous, but default)

Tags: authentication, network, nmap, os-fingerprinting, samba

Over the last couple of years, I've developed a fairly keen interest in ***Penetration Testing*** *&* ***Information Security***. Throughout this time, I've acquired (and accumulated) a range of different devices with network capabilities, primarily, in an effort to learn more about various security auditing techniques. Below is an excerpt of an `nmap` scan of one such device:

---

```
Host script results:
| smb-os-discovery: 
|   OS: Windows 10 Home 10240 (Windows 10 Home 6.3)
|   NetBIOS computer name: MARK
|   Workgroup: WORKGROUP
|_  System time: 2015-09-24T23:38:38-06:00
| smb-security-mode: 
|   Account that was used for smb scripts: <blank>
|   User-level authentication
|   SMB Security: Challenge/response passwords supported   
|_  Message signing disabled (dangerous, but default)
|_smbv2-enabled: Server supports SMBv2 protocol
```

---

My question is specifically regarding the following statement:
`Message signing disabled (dangerous, but default)`.
What is message signing; what is the danger?

Any examples of working exploits would be appreciated.

Comment: Exploit engine here -- https://www.nccgroup.trust/uk/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blogs/2015/november/introducing-chuckle-and-the-importance-of-smb-signing/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Message signing, in this context, refers to SMB (Server Message Block) signing.

Server Message Block (SMB) is a common Windows *"application-layer"* network protocol, and signing is a feature that allows SMB communications to be digitally *"signed"* at the *"packet-level".* The subsequent *"signature"* provides a mechanism by which a recipient can verify the authenticity of a source.

For example, it is important for Domain Controllers to have SMB signing enabled because SMB is the protocol used by clients to download Group Policy information, and SMB signing provides a way to certify that the client is receiving a genuine Group Policy.

SMB signing is supported on all versions of Windows, but is only enabled by default on Domain Controllers.

Nmap is letting you know that:

1. SMB signing is disabled;
2. This is the more dangerous — or less secure — option (as opposed to having SMB signing enabled);
3. This is the default setting for the system you are scanning.

Comment: So basically, it's like a checksum?

Comment: @tjt263 Better than a checksum. If you get 2 messages with the same digital signature, you know they were sent by the same person. Checksums are identical regardless of who added it to a message.